# How to test an application that communicates with another device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, communication

Im a new to developing applications for Apple and i have some questions that i would like to get answered. It was hard to form the question in a correct way thats why i could not find anything that really satisfied me so i turn to you guys!

Im developing an application that will communicate with another device. Like one user will be able to send a request o another user using the same application. Lets say user A sends request to user B. If user B accepts the request then something would happen.

How would i be able to test something like that using simulators? What possible ways are there to test?

Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the simulator for testing, your best bet would be to mock the responses you get back from the requests with "fake" responses. I use OHHTTPStubs for all of my unit tests involving networking stuff and it works great.

https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs